# Aplicação com Crystal Reports não encontra Banco de Dados no cliente

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

Fiz uma pequena aplicação que utiliza Crystal Reports para gerar relatórios.

Fiz o .EXE dele com InstalShield LE, instalei em meu PC e rodou beleza. Porém, quando instalo em outra máquina, o aplicativo não encontra o Banco de Dados setado. Aparece a tela de logon, porém com o Nome do Banco de Dados em branco, enquanto no meu PC entra direto.

A linha que utilizei para setar o logon foi:

```
crVendas.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "senha", "Server", "teste");
```

Tentei inclusive instalar no próprio servidor, mas o mesmo problema ocorre.
Podem me ajudar? Obrigado!

Comment: O Servidor tem o Sql Server instalado? O user sa foi habilitado ?

Comment: publica o stacktrace

Comment: @gmsantos, sim e sim.
A versão do Sql Server é o 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, só para finalizar o caso, acabei resolvendo de maneira bem simples.

Fiz a ligação com o banco de dados direto pelo Database Fields do Crystal Reports e na linha de logon coloquei apenas os dados de acesso:

```
crVendas.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "senha");
```